# Continuous Scroll on Ramotion Expanding Collection

Tags: android

I'm using a library called Expanding Collection by Ramotion, it's at https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection. In the full example given on their Github (and also shown on the GIF on the page), what I want to do is prevent the scroll on the ECPagerView in the middle from stopping once the next card is reached. I want it to go on moving until scroll velocity reaches 0. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].